Unable to get all column names
I am using Selenium to scrape data from a website JODI Data. I am able to scrape the first few column names but the following columns have to be scrolled so the html details and the values (column names) will be updated.
However, I have tried multiple methods suggested by ChatGPT and also Stackoverflow on scrolling horizontal, but the output still remain the same (only get the first 14 column names).
The following is my code. How to capture all columns?
chrome_service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(r'http://www.jodidb.org/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=93905')


time.sleep(5)

col_names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//th[@class="TVItemColHeader"]')


for c in col_names:
    print(c.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

col_lists = []

col_lists = [c.text for c in col_names]

This is the output from outerHTML, the details will only update if its scroll.
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a0">Jan2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a1">Feb2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a2">Mar2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a3">Apr2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a4">May2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a5">Jun2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a6">Jul2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a7">Aug2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a8">Sep2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a9">Oct2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a10">Nov2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a11">Dec2002</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a12">Jan2003</th>
<th class="TVItemColHeader" scope="col" style="border-bottom-style: none" id="a13">Feb2003</th>


Maybe better to select what you want and download csv to post process.

@GillesQuénot Im doing this way, but eventually still need to be automated hence users strongly suggest it to scrap from the link

There are several ways to do this. You can use a vast viewport that accommodates all the columns without the scroller. Or you can scroll and collect the column data one by one. I've done the latter.
In the following example, I have collected all the column names in the header_texts list. You can collect all the data in the same way.
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get(r'http://www.jodidb.org/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=93905')

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'th.TVItemColHeader')))
headers = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'th.TVItemColHeader')
header_texts = []
for header in headers:
    header_texts.append(header.text)

h_scroll = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[@id='hScrollTD']/img[4]").get_attribute('width')
while int(h_scroll)>0:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[@id='hScrollTD']/img[5]").click()
    header_texts.append(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'th.TVItemColHeader:last-child').text)
    h_scroll = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//td[@id='hScrollTD']/img[4]").get_attribute('width')

print(len(header_texts))

